# Speed and acceleration of a curve on a manifold / surface

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces, curves

I need to understand the velocity $\mathbf{r}^{\prime}(p)$ of a curve with parameter $p$, its acceleration $\mathbf{r}^{\prime\prime}(p)$ and the magnitude of a vector on a surface $S$ (or, 2-dimensional manifold).

The surface is defined as $S=S(u,v)$ via the 2 parameters (coordinates) $u$ and $v$

The curve is defined as $\mathbf{r}(p)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u(p)\\
v(p)\\
\end{array}
\right)$
on the surface $S$.

Now, is the speed 
$\mathbf{r}^{\prime}(p)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u^{\prime}(p)\\
v^{\prime}(p)\\
\end{array}
\right)$

and the acceleration

$\mathbf{r}^{\prime\prime}(p)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u^{\prime\prime}(p)\\
v^{\prime\prime}(p)\\
\end{array}
\right)$ ?

How does one calculate the modulus, say, of the speed: is it

$|\mathbf{r}^{\prime}|=\sqrt{(u^{\prime}(p))^2+(v^{\prime}(p))^2}$?

This is how it would be done in Euclidean space, but am unsure if it is true on a manifold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $r:\mathbb{R}\to M$ is a curve on $M$, then we have to look at the differential of $r$.  At a point $y\in \mathbb{R}$, the differential of $r$ is a map $dr_y : T_y\mathbb{R} \to T_{r(y)}M$, where $T_aN$ denotes the tangent space to $N$ at a point $a\in N$.  If our manifold $M$ is $n$-dimensional, then $T_{r(y)}M \cong \mathbb{R}^n$.
In this way we can view the differential of $r$ as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, just like in the 'usual' Euclidean way.

In your case, since $r$ is a parametrized path, we are interested in the evaluation of $dr_y(\hat{x})$, where $\hat{x}$ is a unit vector in the "$x$" direction.  This is called the pushforward of $\hat{x}$ by $r$, and from the definitions we see that $dr_{y}(\hat{x}) \in T_{r(y)}M\cong \mathbb{R}^n$.  In other words, the pushforward of $\hat{x}$ by $r$ is an n-dimensional vector, which we can think of as the velocity of $r$ at the point $r(y)$.  You can then compute the speed of $r$ by taking the magnitude of this vector, for example.

Comment: How would my simple notation fit into this terminology... All I have is a surface S(u,v) and a curve with parameter p; and vectors r' and r''.

Comment: I've read this answer probably... N times. What I get is, that yes, since the differential dr is a map from R into R2, we can do things the ususal, 'Euclidean' way. This means the expressions for speed, acceleration and vector length are correct as written above.

Comment: Also, it matches what I read in a text by A. Pressley... According to him, the speed of a curve is a vector with coordinates (u',v') on the surface, where the basis is made by 2 vectors Su and Sv (the partial derivatives of S w/respect to u and v). So I will take your answer as a 'yes'.

Comment: @user142523 Since your surface $S$ appears to be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, all of the 'usual' formulas work.  I misunderstood your question, and I thought that you were looking for a more theoretical understanding of the situation.  In your case, the formulas you have written are correct.